# Music Genre Recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Today I was exploring this part  and have referred this link https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-project-music-genre-classification/
 While i was excuting i got a error at this part

```
`directory = "genres"
f= open("my.dat" ,'wb')
i=0
for folder in os.listdir(directory):
    i+=1
    if i==11 :
        break   
    for file in os.listdir(directory+folder):  
        (rate,sig) = wav.read(directory+folder+"/"+file)
        mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate ,winlen=0.020, appendEnergy = False)
        covariance = np.cov(np.matrix.transpose(mfcc_feat))
        mean_matrix = mfcc_feat.mean(0)
        feature = (mean_matrix , covariance , i)
        pickle.dump(feature , f)
f.close()`
```

[image: The files are not found]

Can anyone say whatb went wrong

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, never post images of code/errors in your question - copy the code/errors instead. Also, By looking at your error, you see that the problem is inside the loop - and is therefore not related to genre recognition, nlp or anything like that; a minimal example would have `pass` inside the internal for-loop. Pay attention to those things in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are providing a wrong path to read the files. Update the code which reads the file in your directory -

```
for file in os.listdir(directory+'/'+folder):   
        (rate,sig) = wav.read(directory+'/'+folder+"/"+file)
```

directory+folder (+ concatenates 2 strings) Output = genresbextract_single.mf(assuming bextract_single.mf is your folder name), which is an invalid path.

directory+'/'+'bextract_single.mf' Output = genres/bextract_single.mf, which is a valid path, and listdir will read all the files in that path.